# Subtract and get a clean number from the total length of the array [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I have this code here:

```
function likes(names) {
  if (names.length == 0) {
    return 'no one likes this';
}  else if (names.length >= 4) {
    return names[0]+ ', ' + names[1] + ' and' + names.length - 2 + 'others like this';
}  else if (names.length <4 && names.length >0){
return names[0] + ', ' + names[1] +' and ' + names[2] +' like this'
}}
```

My main problem is in line 5. I need to subtract 2 from the length of the array and concat that to the string. Unfortunately for me, I have no idea how this can be done, and mine is wrong, obviously. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose the numeric subexpression in parentheses to prevent it from being part of the larger string concatenation process:

```
return names[0]+ ', ' + names[1] + ' and ' + (names.length - 2) + ' others like this';
```

With that, the numeric subtraction subexpression will be evaluated separately, and the *result* of it will be concatenated into the string.

Comment: Additionally, in `else if (names.length <4 && names.length >0)` `&& names.length >0` is redundant. You checked it in `if (names.length == 0)`

Comment: Also it is good idea to rearrange conditions. 1) `== 0`, 2) `< 4`, and 3) `else` which means `>=4`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Sure that's true. I was just addressing the immediate issue.

Comment: I addressed to the questioner ;)

Comment: Thanks Alex, although replying to the main question would've been better.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to [Pointy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36973562/1529630), template strings are cleaner in my opinion:

```
return `${names[0]}, ${names[1]} and ${names.length - 2} others like this`;
```

Comment: They might be cleaner (though for simple cases I'm not 100% convinced), but they're not supported in any IE version (including Edge) as far as I know.

Comment: Actually it looks like [Edge support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-template_strings) for template literals is pretty good. IE11 lacks support completely, however.